# Show that cubic hamiltonian graph is edge-3-colourable.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, hamiltonian-path

How can I show that cubic hamiltonian graph is edge-3-colourable?

Answer (score 1):

Find a proper 3-edge colouring explicitly. Start with the Hamiltonian cycle, then colour the remaining edges.